# Why Visual Studio 2017 returns error while installing cvxpy 0.4.11?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, package, cvxpy

I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 online with python enabled. under `Python Environments > Packages` I search for `cvxpy` and it suggest installing `"pip install cvxpy" from PyPI`. but when I click on it, process returns an error saying: `error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2`.

What is that error for and how Can I solve it?

Comment: Read the official docs. It's not recommended to use pip on windows for this (= installing cvxpy).

Comment: @sascha what is the substitute? I just select package and visual studio selects the way to install package by itself

Comment: If you are not experienced with building software from sources you should follow any anaconda-based path, as explained in the docs. If that's a working combination together with visual studio, you will have to check. To be honest: the (non-)details you gave indicate that you are not that experienced. The error you posted contains almost no information. That's the one printed whenever something goes wrong during building (and there are tons of potential reasons; here: probably some problem during build of cvxcanon, ECOS, or SCS if scipy already available; if not you are in big trouble).